# So I've restarted my While-loop program and now am getting all NaN or they aren't saving the text I input

Tags: javascript, while-loop, accumulator

I need to write a program for a wedding planner. They wish to create a gift registry for each couple. They want the gifts broken down by the whether the gift giver is on the bride side or groom side. They also know that specific gifts (toasters, silverware, and stemware) tend to be repeated so they want those gifts listed and have the name of the gift giver under them. The repeating gifts are only the ones that have been told you by the client (toasters, silverware, and stemware) they do not want you to determine which gifts repeat, they are just looking for those specific three. So I can implement code for only silverware, stemware, and toasters, which I have this time. But now I cannot get any correct output.

After the program has run, it should have a printout somewhat like this.

> Groom side:
>
> 1. Tom: toaster
> 2. Bill: silverware
> 3. Bob: stemware
> 4. Steve: Lexus
>
> Bride side:
>
> 1. Jill: toaster
> 2. Suzy: silverware
> 3. Pat: stemware
> 4. Karen: horse
>
> Multiple toasters by:
>
> Tom
>
> Jill
>
> Multiple silverware by:
>
> Bill
>
> Suzy
>
> Multiple stemware by:
>
> Bob
>
> Pat

Here is what I've got so far...

```
var guestName;
var gift, side, kind, groomNameAccum, brideNameAccum;
var toaster, silverware, stemware, giftType;
var toasterAccum, silverwareAccum, stemwareAccum;
var noGift = 0;
var groomCounter = 0;
var brideCounter = 0;
//initalizing loop
var guest = "yes";
//start loop
while (guest == "yes") {
    side = prompt("Which side are you on? groom or bride?", "");
    guestName = prompt("Whats your name?", "");
    kind = prompt("What kind of gift?", "");

    if (side == "groom") {
        groomCounter = groomCounter + 1;
        if (groomCounter == 1) {
            groomNameAccum = "Groom     side:     <br>" + groomCounter + ". " + guestName + ": " + kind;
        } else {
            groomNameAccum = groomNameAccum + "<br>" + groomCounter + ". " + guestName + ": " + kind;
        }
    } else
    if (side == "bride") {
        brideCounter = brideCounter + 1;
        if (brideCounter == 1) {
            brideNameAccum = "<p>Bride side: <br>" + brideCounter + ". " + guestName + ": " + kind;
        } else {
            brideNameAccum = brideNameAccum + "<br>" + brideCounter + ". " + guestName + ": " + kind;
        }
    }

    if (kind == "toaster") 
        {
        toasterAccum = toasterAccum + "; " + guestName;
        }
     else if(kind == "silverware")
          {
            silverwareAccum= silverwareAccum + "; " + guestName; 
            }else if (kind == "stemware") 
            {
             stemwareAccum = stemwareAccum + "; " + guestName
            }
            else 
            {
             multiples = 0; 
             } 
    guest = prompt("Are there anymore guests?", "yes");
}


document.write(groomNameAccum);
document.write(brideNameAccum);
document.write("<p>Multiple Toasters by:<br>" + toasterAccum + "<br/>");
document.write("Multiple Silverware by:<br>" + silverwareAccum + "<br/>");
document.write("Multiple Stemware by:<br>" + stemwareAccum + "<br/>");
```

As I was saying, my teacher doesn't try to teach us the shortcuts and easy stuff, because it is a classroom of technical college students. I know there are easier ways to write it out, but I don't know how yet. Hes got his formula for success that always leads me looking for correct answers....

Comment: We will not solve this for you. First of all all seems wrong. Check again stuff like parse int and then comparing it with string. Also most of you variables are referenced before setting values.

Comment: This is how our teacher has taught us to code...I know it looks wrong, if parse int isnt what I need, how do I recall what is inputted into what kind of gift? I know i'm no master coder, but I am trying to learn. I edited the code to take out the parseInt. And as for the variables are referenced before setting values, what do you mean. Like setting my var's at the top? Cause that just how my teacher likes to see our work.

Comment: So changed the parseInt and a few other variables and am still getting  this at the very end. 

Multiples Toasters by:
undefined karen
Multiples Silverware by:
undefined karen
Multiples Stemware by:
undefined karen

So there is an undefined number somewhere that shouldn't be showing up in my Multiples section. And only using the last person I put in everything else is coming out just fine...

Groom side: 
1. tom: toaster
2. bill: silverware
3. bob: stemware
4. steve: lexus
Bride side: 
1. jill: toaster
2. suzy: silverware
3. pat: stemware
4. karen: horse

Comment: This exercise may teach you something useful if you discover arrays and how to use them.  Looking at your existing code - look at the last three lines.  You are writing three blocks out - but the variables in the blocks are the same - so the text would be the same.  Get your head around the implications of that and what you, therefore, need to do earlier in your programme to produce the required output (clue: you are going to need a different variable to hold the guest names that bought each type of gift).

Comment: Thanks for actually helping instead of just brushing me off :) Everyone could edit my writing but not the code. At least you've sent me in a direction.

Comment: Could I also just do a simple accumulator for toasters, stemware, and silverware?